# Resizing of images in table only works for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, resize, css

I am having trouble with image resizing in tables in my current website project.

While basically all images in the page content are getting resized to the containers width (caused by the Twitter Bootstrap framework I am using for layout) I found out that for images in tables it does only work in Chrome. With other browser engines, resizing is ignored (only) for tables. I thought using `max-width: 100%` for resizing is working in all cases.

Before you ask me, for certain pages use of html tables is intended, because people without knowledge of html should also be able to easily edit the page (so I need them, sorry).

The url of the page is: http://kunden.tommy-computer.at/fsv_noetsch/?page_id=35

A stripped-down version of the problem can be seen [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yv4jb/8).

This is what the page should look like for small browser resolutions (correct behaviour, but works in Chrome only):
[image]

This is what it looks like in other browsers (image is not resized, table columns do not have 50% width, wrong at all):
[image]

I can`t figure out how to fix this and also do not have a better approach for it. Maybe you can help me out. Thank you !

Comment: would really more handy if it was a jsfiddle.net or codepen.io or liveweave.com(works under IE8) with just what troubles you :) 99% of html or CSS is a drag to go through untill we get to the style/HTML. It might even brings you the solution while you extract your problem. Thx

Comment: Don't use tables for layout.

Comment: ok, sorry, here is the fiddle with reproduceable behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/Yv4jb/6/

Comment: Your fiddle is useless. You did't *extract* anything, but just pasted your code as is. You were expected to post as little code as possible, that still exhibits the problematic behaviour.

Comment: Ok sorry, did not have a lot of time yesterday any more. Here is a very basic fiddle of it, hope it is like it should be now: http://jsfiddle.net/Yv4jb/8/  Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `table-layout: fixed;` attribute to your table (tested OK with Firefox).